# How do we know that β is algebraic over F?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

[image]

The picture above is a screenshot from section 5, chapter 14, Artin's *Algebra*, 1st edition, which is about primitive elements and their applications in Galois theory.

I have difficulty to understand the proof of Proposition (4.4). The proof shown in the book is based on the fact that *β* is algebraic over *F*, but what I found most difficult in this proof is exactly to show *β* is an algebraic element.

(This does sound weird. I guess I might miss some elementary result in the previous chapters and lack some basic knowledge in field theory, since I started reading it from the middle part of the chapter. It could also be because I don't fully understand the Primitive element theorem, which lies right above Proposition (4.4).)

Could anyone help me to understand why *β* is algebraic over *F*? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The coefficients of $g(x)$ are fixed by $G$, because $G$ permutes its roots which are simple.

Comment: @reuns Thanks. It seems to me that given the existence of a group G of automorphisms of a field K, we can always deduce the fact that K is algebraic over the fixed field F of G in the same way as you have shown. Is it correct?

Comment: *Finite* group of automorphisms (try with $\Bbb{R}(x)$ having $x\to 2x$ in its automorphisms whose fixed subfield is $\Bbb{R}$)

Comment: @reuns I get what you said. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: It's a standard result that under these conditions $K$ is a finite extension of $F$ of degree same as order of $G$. And then every element of $K$ is algebraic over $F$ (as every finite degree extension is algebraic).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Sure. But actually in Artin's book (and in many analogues such as Lang's Algebra), the result in your comment is derived after proving Proposition 4.4 as a 
lemma, by using the degree over $F$ of any given element $α$ in $K$ (which is shown in Proposition 4.4) and the primitive element theorem. Anyway, thanks.